# To what extent can caching destroy my Flask App?

Tags: flask, browser-cache, flask-wtforms

I created a flask web application that only runs locally and is used to fill out forms. When the form is filled out, it automatically records it in an excel file and sends emails. Since the application stays on 24/7, I was wondering how the web browser's cache could crash my program? I did not write code anywhere stating to use the browser's cache, but I am worrying that this could be something I need to think about as I am finding that it affected people who had created web apps previously. So I was wondering how caching in my situation could crash my program? Users simply type their name and fill out responses to questions.

I have placed the following code in my routes.py but I still see the browser saving user names so I don't think it cleared the cache:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    r.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify cache in your flask app or in the server configuration, there won't be any cache handled by the server.

But it can be done automatically by the client-side. If there is an autosuggestion on the input, this is done by the browser.

You can disable it directly on the input with `autocomplete="off"`

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>
```